Custom validator in Bean - JF specification
I need a custom validator to sum up selected checkboxes within a per ui:repeat built structure. That works pretty good but the question is if this is a valid validator since I don't care the regular signature FacesComponent fc, UIComponent ui, Object o) for this:
<h:inputHidden
  value="true"
  validator="#{myBean.validate(foo, bar)}"
  validatorMessage="Error" />

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  public void validate(final ComplexObject a, final int b) {
    if (...) {
      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage());
    }
  }
}

It that valid in view to the JF specification? What are the disadvantages?
